# Should I move from has_many :through to has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
class Room
  has_many :room_markers
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_markers
end

class Marker
...
end

class RoomMarker
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :marker
end
```

I have a set of classes as mentioned above.

Now I realize that `Room` could have `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with `Maeker` instead of `has_many_through`

Now my question is "Should I refactor those models? to have  `has_and_belongs_to_many` association instead of `has_many_through`".

Is there any performance related issue if I continue with the existing design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler is better. You should refactor if you don't need the extra model.

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if     you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).

From the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

I don't think you have to worry about performance at this level, just take the solution that fits your needs.

Comment: I guess, its about the convention mostly. And there might have  performance issue a bit as one extra model is there.